# Singular Solutions of this Equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, singular-integrals

How would I find the singular solutions of this equation:

y = $ce^{x^2}$ + $ce^{\sin x}$ (where $c$ is a constant).

It should be $x^2$ if anyone gets confused by the first part of the equation.

Would I just find the zeroes of the equation? Such as $x = 0$ & $x = n*\pi$ where $n$ is an element of the Reals?

Hope someone can help, thanks guys.

Comment: I have edited you rquestion and please check if it is OKay or not.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Hopeless Fool , it's appreciated my friend.

Comment: Will it be $y$ or $\dot{y}$?

Comment: The original equation should be with the $y$ . Thanks. By the way, do you know what the singular solutions are for this?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: No worries, will hope someone can answer it. But thank you for the edit mate, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "singular solutions"?  That term is usually used for differential equations, but there's no differential equation in sight.

Comment: That's right.. the original differential equation was solved to get what I posted.

Comment: I'm afraid nobody can help you if you do not give the original differential equation. You show some set of solutions (which may or may not be correct) and ask what other solutions are there. How can anyone tell without knowing the equation?